# Using an array as an active list with unique values in VBA for Excel data

Tags: arrays, excel, list, vba, for-loop

I am trying to figure out how I can use VBA to create an array from Excel data as an active list that can have unique entries added and removed automatically as my script runs through a loop.

Example:

```
Object#   ,  Status     ,   Group#  ,  Time            
1      ,     Associate     , 1        , 1  
1      ,     Associate     , 1        , 1.1  
1      ,     Associate     , 2        , 2   
1      ,     Associate     , 3        , 3  
1      ,     Disassociate  , 2        , 4
```

The array would populate unique combinations of `Object`, `Status`, and `Group` but `Time` would not matter because once an object is associated it will remain associated until it is disassociated.

I have looked for help on this but most posts only discuss populating the array and do not discuss how a loop could help to automatically remove an entry when it is disassociated.

So in this example I would want an system that would allow me to enter the object # and time then the script would run and at the end it would tell me that "At time 4, object 1 is associated with groups 1 and 3". An alternate scenario would be "At time 3, object 1 is associated with groups 1, 2, 3". Finally, if at time 5 all objects were disassociated the the message would display the last group the object was associated to.

I have a code that does everything I need until it runs into a situation where an object is associated to more than one group then it fails to return accurate information. My programming knowledge is limited so your help is appreciated. Below is the code I have currently where Cells (15, 8) and (18, 8) are value input cells for Object # and Time.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim Association As String, i As Integer, Group As Integer

Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))

For i = 1 To Count 

    If Cells (i, 1).Value = Cells(15, 8) And Cells (i, 4).Value <= Cells (18, 8) And Cells (i, 2) = "Associate"  Then Association = "Associated" 

    If Cells (i, 1).Value = Cells(15, 8) And Cells (i, 4).Value <= Cells (18, 8) And Cells (i, 2) = "Disassociate"  Then Association = "NOT Associated"

    If Cells (i, 1).Value = Cells(15, 8) And Cells (i, 4).Value <= Cells (18, 8) And Cells (i, 2) = "Associate"  Then Group = Cells(i, 3)

Next i

    If Association = "Associated" Then MsgBox Association & " Associated to " & Group
    If Association = "NOT Associated" Then Msgbox Association & " Was Last Associated to " & Group
    If Association = "" Then Msgbox "Object Does Not Exist Prior to This Time"

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please share with us the already obtained code for the simplicity? Just edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some back-and-forth you & I discover that this is a more complicated request than we had initially understood it.  Here is another method that uses a `Scripting.Dictionary` object -- basically this allows you to add/remove unique "Keys" to a collection. In this case I chose to use Group# as the KEY value, because you indicate that this should be the unique association (e.g., if Obj1 is associated to Group 1 at Time 1 and Group 1 at Time 2, we only care about the first association to Group 1). Further we assume that Time is always sorted ascending.

Scripting.Dictionary seems perhaps a little easier than trying to resize arrays for your add/remove.

At the end, we set some simple arrays `dicKeys` and `dicItems`, over which we can iterate to present the message box information to user.  In your example, it will create a message box as follows:

[image: screenshot of msgbox result]

Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub GroupAssociation()
'ASSUMPTIONS: GroupNum is the UNIQUE key
'ASSUMPTIONS: TimeVal always sort ascending

'Parameters for our test:
Dim ObjNum As Integer  'cells(15,5)
Dim TimeStamp As Double 'cells(15,8)

'Fields being iterated over, in columns A:D
Dim i As Integer    'row counter/iterator
Dim count As Long   'row count/max range
Dim ObjTest As Integer 'the object number being tested, from column A, cells(i,1)
Dim Status As String  'cells(i,2)
Dim GroupNum As Integer  'cells(1,3)
Dim TimeVal As Double  'Cells(i,4)

'We will store the information, uniquely in a Scripting.Dictionary
Dim objDic As Object 'Scripting dictionary to contain your information
Dim dicKeys As Variant 'list of key items in the dictionary
Dim dicItems As Variant 'list of items in dictionary
Dim o As Long 'counter/iterator for dicKeys

'A message box will display the results
Dim mbString As String 'to contain the message box string

Set objDic = Nothing 'make sure this is nothing, just in case.
Set objDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))

ObjNum = Cells(15, 8).Value
TimeStamp = Cells(18, 8).Value

For i = 2 To count
    ObjTest = Cells(i, 1).Value
    Status = Cells(i, 2).Value
    GroupNum = Cells(i, 3).Value
    TimeVal = Cells(i, 4).Value
    dicKeys = objDic.Keys

    If ObjTest = ObjNum And TimeVal <= TimeStamp Then
        If Status = "Associate" Then
            'Check to see if this Key already exists, if so ignore, if not, add to dic.
            If UBound(dicKeys) < 0 Then
                objDic.Add GroupNum, "Object #" & ObjTest & _
                    " Associated to Group #" & GroupNum & " at time " & TimeVal
            Else:
                If IsError(Application.Match(GroupNum, dicKeys, False)) Then
                    objDic.Add GroupNum, "Object #" & ObjTest & _
                    " Associated to Group #" & GroupNum & " at time " & TimeVal
                End If
            End If
        ElseIf Status = "Disassociate" Then
            'Check to see if this Key already exists, if so, remove it
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(GroupNum, dicKeys, False)) Then
                'remove the item as it was
                objDic.Remove GroupNum
                'add a new item indicating it's new status as disassociated
                objDic.Add GroupNum, "Object #" & ObjTest & _
                " Disassociated from Group #" & GroupNum & " at time " & TimeVal
            End If
        End If
    End If

Next i

'Set some arrays from our Dictionary items:
dicKeys = objDic.Keys
dicItems = objDic.Items

'iterate over the array and build our message box string:
For o = 0 To UBound(dicKeys)
    If mbString = vbNullString Then
        mbString = dicKeys(o) & " - " & dicItems(o)
    Else:
        mbString = mbString & vbCrLf & _
           dicKeys(o) & " - " & dicItems(o)
    End If
Next

'handle cases where the item doesn't exist prior to this timestamp:
If mbString = vbNullString Then mbString = "Object #" & ObjNum & _
    " doesn't exist prior to time " & TimeStamp

'Show the message box:
MsgBox mbString, vbInformation

Set objDic = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes I did pick a diffult task to begin learning with :) It is a necessary task and will greatly reduce processing time for data. It started out small, and I almost had it working with my first bit of code, but the snag I ran into complicated matters very quickly as you have realized while helping me. I cannot express enough how helpful you have been in solving this with me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You're mostly there. For this example I would `Dim Group as String` and build a simple comma-separated list to allow for multiple associations. You could store this as an array and transpose it but I'm not sure that would be necessary.

I declared a few more variables to facilitate making a cleaner/tidier "test", and favor `Select Case` rather than multiple IF/THEN for your message box results.

```
Private Sub Groups()
Dim Association As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim Group As String 'will contain the message
Dim ObjNum As Integer  'cells(15,5)
Dim TimeStamp As Double 'cells(15,8)
Dim ObjTest As Integer
Dim Status As String  'cells(i,2)
Dim GroupNum As Integer  'cells(1,3)
Dim TimeVal As Double  'Cells(i,4)

Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))

ObjNum = Cells(15, 8).Value
TimeStamp = Cells(18, 8).Value

For i = 2 To Count
    ObjTest = Cells(i, 1).Value
    Status = Cells(i, 2).Value
    GroupNum = Cells(i, 3).Value
    TimeVal = Cells(i, 4).Value

    If ObjTest = ObjNum And TimeVal <= TimeStamp Then
        If Status = "Associate" Then
            Association = "Associated"
            'Build a simple comma-delimited string of group associations, to allow
            ' for multiple associations
            Group = PrintMessage(Group, GroupNum & " at time " & TimeVal)
        ElseIf Status = "Disassociate" Then
            Association = "NOT Associated"
        End If
    End If

Next i

Select Case Association
    Case "Associated"
        MsgBox "Object # " & ObjNum & " Associated to: " & vbCrLf & Group
    Case "NOT Associated"
        MsgBox "Object # " & ObjNum & " Was Last Associated to: " & vbCrLf & Group
    Case vbNullString, ""
        MsgBox "Object " & ObjNum & " Does Not Exist Prior to This Time"
End Select

End Sub


Function PrintMessage(existingMsg$, GroupAtTimeString$) As String
If existingMsg = vbNullString Then
    PrintMessage = GroupAtTimeString
Else:
    PrintMessage = existingMsg & "," & vbCrLf & GroupAtTimeString
End If
End Function
```

Comment: This seems to be very close to what I need and I greatly appreciate it. I have two issues that are coming up.                               1. There can be multiple entries of the same association so when the message comes up there are multiple entries reported for the same group i.e. I need a unique message if the object 1 is associated to group 1 at 2 different times. "Associated to Group 1 and 1" Versus "Associated to Group 1"      2.) It seems that i am having issues when I enter a time that has a decimal ie 200.26 vs 200. Is there a way to fix this issue? Again I appreciate your help!

Comment: as long as `TimeVal` and `TimeStamp` variables are dimensioned as Double, you should not have any issue with a decimal.  If so you will need to describe in more detail.  For your first request depending on what sort of information you want to display, this could be done pretty easily. Do you simply want a message that says "Object X is associated to Group 1 at 2 different times"? What about multiple multiple associations (e.g., group 1 has 2 associations and group 3 has 2 associations?  This quickly becomes a problem that you **need** an array to resolve.

Comment: @KrisLeatherman see revision above. Made a few changes to give you more information/detail in the msgbox if multiple associations exist, e.g., "Object # 1 is associated with Group 1 at Time 1, Group 1 at Time 1.1"

Comment: I appologize in that the decimal is not a problem. It was a user error. As for the multiple associations, if Object #1 is associated with Group 1 at Time 1 and associated with Group 1 again at Time 1.1 I only need to know that it was associated the first time (aka unique values after the first association of a specific number). It is like a tv with an on button & an off button in that once it is associated it is "on" and you can push the on button as many times as you want without any change, but you only have to push the "off" button once to turn it off. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: What if Object1 is associated with Group 1 at time 1, and Group 2 at time 2? Show both associations or only the most recent?

Comment: @ David Both of those cases would be important... for a given group, only the first association would be important and not any duplicate associations.

Comment: Will the TIME column always be sorted in ascending order?

Comment: Yes, The time column will always be in ascending order.

Comment: In your example at time 4 obj#1 disassociates from Group 2, do the associations to groups 1 and 3 remain? Or is the disassociation universal in that the object disassociates from ALL groups?

Comment: The associations to groups 1 and 3 remain until they are specifically disassociated.

Comment: Well now you have an issue of MULTIPLE messages that may need to appear for any given object, since the "Object was last associated to:..." message doesn't seem applicable if the object is still associated with groups 1 and 3.

Comment: In this instance it would be appropriate to indicate that "The object is currently associated to Groups 1 and 3" The "last associated" message is only applicable if the object has been disassociated from ALL groups.

Comment: So that was not part of your original request.

Comment: I appologize, I have been trying to put this program together and learn how to code in VBA at the same time. This is my first code ever, and I have been piecemealing it together from the start. Your help is GREATLY appreciated. . . I cannot understate that. I will continue to work on it and again I would like to thank you for your help. It is soo close to being complete all thanks to you.

Comment: One more question....In your screenshot, the output box numbers the line items as 1, 3, 2. Where do these numbers come from? Can they be removed? Thanks again.

Comment: In the `For` loop where we iterate over the array and build our message box string,  remove both instances of `dicKeys(o) & " - " & ` (first instance in the `IF` block, second instance in the `ELSE` block).

Comment: I have run into a few instances where there are too many returns of "disassociate from group x at time y" to fit in the message box. I have tried to manipulate the code to remove the "disassociate" clause so that the message box only shows current associations. I keep running into errors and was hoping you might be able to help out once again. Thanks for your time.